# Handling nested dictionaries in Meteor and mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dictionary, meteor, handlebars.js

I have the following structure:

```
{
  game_number: 101,
  type: 1,
  players: ["x1","x2","x3"],
  scores: [
            { "x1" : 0 },
            { "x2" : 1 }
          ]
}
```

There is a *game* in which 3 *players* are playing. Players *x1* and *x2* have already finished and have their final scores. Player *x3* has not finished yet. My idea was to check the *scores* in this structure and see who has already finished or not so I can have in Meteor something like:

```
{{#if playerHasFinished player}}
  <div class="result">
    ...
  </div>
{{else}}
  <div class="waiting">
    ...
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

I am not sure if I am structuring my data correctly, so maybe *there* is my "functional" mistake, but it should be possible to do it anyway, right? How would I access that data?

Comment: Is this game in your database rather then being a javascript object?  Presumably you know which game you're referring to, or at least what the player is called (x1, x2, etc...)?

Comment: Not sure I get the question. You talk about mistake before you tell us what the problem is. What is the code for `playerHasFinished`?

Comment: Sorry guys, I wrote this question a little on a hurry and the I realized that it was indeed a bit confusing. Thanks for your time and help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for an implementation of `playerHasFinished`, here is an example:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  playerHasFinished: function(player) {
    // get the current game - modify as appropriate
    var game = Games.findOne(Session.get('curentGame'));

    // ['x1', 'x2']
    var finishedPlayers = _.keys(scores);

    // this assumes player is a string like 'x3'
    return _.contains(finishedPlayers, player);
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in the question. Yes, in the end I was asking that, and this helped me a lot. Thanks!